# Recursive SQL query on nested-set tree with stop condition

Tags: mysql, sql, data-structures, tree, mariadb

I am using a nested-set tree structure in a table. The concept is described [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

The example data looks as follow:

```
+----+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
| id | parent_id | left | right | stop_descending |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 |      NULL |    1 |    10 |               0 |
|  2 |         1 |    2 |     3 |               0 |
|  3 |         1 |    4 |     9 |               1 |
|  4 |         3 |    5 |     6 |               0 |
|  5 |         3 |    7 |     8 |               0 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+-----------------+
```

Getting the whole tree is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM nested_set AS t0
LEFT JOIN nested_set AS t1 ON t0.left BETWEEN t1.left AND t1.right
WHERE t1.parent_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t0.left;
```

However, I would like to get all nodes whose parent has not a stop_ descending flag. The result should include nodes 1,2,3. Nodes 4,5 should be excluded as their parent has the stop_ descending flag. If nodes 4 and 5 would have children, these should be excluded as well. The recursion should stop, once the is_leaf value equals 1.

I tried many different approaches but never got the proper result. Im am running the query in MariaDB 10.1.26. Maybe there a better solution involing CTE on higher version.

Comment: parent and is_leaf both seem a little redundant, no?

Comment: I just changed the column names. This should describe the actual question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do another self join to check if that leaf is part of a node with `stop_decending = 1`

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6f967/4)**

```
SELECT t0.*, t1.*, t3.*
FROM nested_set AS t0
LEFT JOIN nested_set AS t1 
  ON t0.left BETWEEN t1.left AND t1.right

LEFT JOIN nested_set as t3
  ON t0.id BETWEEN t3.left AND t3.right
 AND t3.stop_descending  = 1

WHERE t1.parent_id IS NULL
  AND t3.id IS NULL
ORDER BY t0.left;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | parent_id | left | right | stop_descending | id | parent_id | left | right | stop_descending |     id | parent_id |   left |  right | stop_descending |
|----|-----------|------|-------|-----------------|----|-----------|------|-------|-----------------|--------|-----------|--------|--------|-----------------|
|  1 |    (null) |    1 |    10 |               0 |  1 |    (null) |    1 |    10 |               0 | (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |          (null) |
|  2 |         1 |    2 |     3 |               0 |  1 |    (null) |    1 |    10 |               0 | (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |          (null) |
|  3 |         1 |    4 |     9 |               1 |  1 |    (null) |    1 |    10 |               0 | (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |          (null) |
```

For debug comment the filter `AND t3.id IS NULL`

Comment: This just returns the root node for me. Furthermore, it would only cover the direct children of that node.

Comment: Please check again.